# MySQL: Getting adjacent rows of value in indexed column in table

Tags: mysql

I've a table `ALL_VALUES` having single column `VALUE` which is indexed.

```
VALUE
3
6
10
11
17
18
18
21
25
25
29
```

Now if I know a particular value say 17, I like to fetch rows that include 17 and top and bottom adjacent 3 rows i.e. 6, 10, 11, 17, 18, 18, 21.

How shall I write `SELECT` query for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm used to MSSQL. But I think this might work:

```
  Select t1.value from((SELECT value
    FROM ALL_VALUES
    WHERE value <= 17
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 4)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT value
    FROM ALL_VALUES
    WHERE value > 17
    LIMIT 3)) t1 order by value ASC;
```

Comment: it won't work....read what OP actually wants...he wants 6,10,11 before 17 as per your query it will return 3,6,10

Comment: This answer is missing the matching `ORDER BY value DESC` and `... ASC` respectively.

Comment: @Joyce Still won't work....also i guess the `order by` should come before `limit`...the output here would be like 17,11,10,18,18,20....but the desired output should be 6,10,11,17,18,18,20

Comment: @Joyce: Current answer returns me: '6'
'10'
'11'
'17'
'18'
'21'